# Adobe PDF JavaScript формы: групировка If…else синтаксиса

Tags: javascript, pdf, форма, синтаксис, forms

Имеется документ с формами в PDF, ввод пользователя проверяется с помощью JavaScript. Пользователь выбирает различные опции в формах, и взависимости от выбора на икране появляються различные лейблы. Пример кода ниже:

```js
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("countryofgrowth").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("sugarquality").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("cornquantitymax").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("cornquantity").value;
var type = this.getField("type").value;

if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == "Afghanistan [AF]" || countryofgrowth == "Albania [AL]" || countryofgrowth == "Algeria [DZ]" || countryofgrowth == "Angola [AO]" || countryofgrowth == "Argentina [AR]" || ……) )
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.visible;
       getField("goodsugar").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
}
else if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == "Australia [AU]" || countryofgrowth == "Belgium [BE]" || countryofgrowth == "Canada [CA]" || countryofgrowth == "Czech Republic [CZ]" || countryofgrowth == "Denmark [DK]" || …..))
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;   
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;          

    if (sugarquality == "Low Quality")
    {
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
    }
    else if (sugarquality == "High Quality")
    {
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;

       if (sugarQualitylevelhigh == " More than 75%")
        {
         getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
        }
        else if (sugarQualitylevelhigh == "Less than 75%")
        {
            getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
        }
    }
}
else if ((type == "Corn") && (countryofgrowth == "Aland Islands [AX]" || countryofgrowth == "Alderney" || countryofgrowth == "American Samoa [AS]" || countryofgrowth == "Andorra [AD]" || countryofgrowth == "Anguilla [AI]" || countryofgrowth == "Antarctica [AQ]" || ……))
{
      getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;  
      getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
      getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
      getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
      getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
      getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;

    if (cornquantity == "More than 500t")
    {
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.visible;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
    }
    else if (cornquantity == "More than 1000t")
    {
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.visible;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;

        if (cornquantitymax == "Yes")
        {
         getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
        }
        else if (cornquantitymax == "No")
        {
            getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.visible;
        }
    }
}
```

На данный момент моя проблема заключается в том что в синтаксе с странами, оператор `||` - имеет то 30 до 90 стран, в зависимости от синтиксиса. У меня сейчас есть 4 разных синтаксиса с разными странами в каждом. Как можно сгрупировать 4 групы под 4 разные переменные?

В идеале хотель бы что то на подобии примера указанного ниже, *код представленный ниже не работает, представил только для примера*:

```js
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("countryofgrowth").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("sugarquality").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("cornquantitymax").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("cornquantity").value;
var type = this.getField("type").value;

var Highriskcountries = ["Afghanistan [AF]", "Albania [AL]", "Algeria [DZ]", "Angola [AO]", "Argentina [AR]", .....];

var Lowriskcountries = ["Australia [AU]", "Belgium [BE]", "Canada [CA]", "Czech Republic [CZ]", "Denmark [DK]", .....];

var Mediumriskcountries = ["Aland Islands [AX]", "Alderney", "American Samoa [AS]", "Andorra [AD]", "Anguilla [AI]", "Antarctica [AQ]", .....];

var Acceptablecountries = ["Aland Islands [AX]", "Alderney", "American Samoa [AS]", "Andorra [AD]", "Anguilla [AI]", "Antarctica [AQ]", "Australia [AU]", "Belgium [BE]", "Canada [CA]", "Czech Republic [CZ]", "Denmark [DK]", .....];

if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == Highriskcountries))
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.visible;
       getField("goodsugar").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
}
else if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == Lowriskcountries))
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;   
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;          
 }
```

Приблизительно вот так выглядит моя форма:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Ниже я представил пример текстовых полей в которых храниться мой код, на данный момент мой код работает, проблема в том что синтаксисы с If...Else со всеми странами занимают много строк кода и он не влазит в одно текстовое поле, потому приходится перекидывать в несколько, но к сожалению так как некоторые из моих If...Else синтаксисов имеют большое количество под синтаксисов, я не могу разделить их между текстовыми полями, потому надеялся решить проблему групировкой стран что бы с экономить количество строк кода + код получиться аккуратный. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов засунуть их в массив и проверять через [indexOf функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var AcceptableCountries = ["Aland Islands [AX]", "Alderney", "American Samoa [AS]", "Andorra [AD]", "Anguilla [AI]", "Antarctica [AQ]", "Australia [AU]", "Belgium [BE]", "Canada [CA]", "Czech Republic [CZ]", "Denmark [DK]"];

var countryofgrowth = "Czech Republic [CZ]";
if(AcceptableCountries.indexOf(countryofgrowth) != -1){
    console.log("okay");
}
```

Так же Вы можете сократить себе код вставив установку полей в функцию.

```js
var setDisplay = function(display){
  var fields = ["sugarlabel", "goodsugar", "sugarQualitylevellow" /*,...*/];
    for(var i=0; i< fields.length; i++){
      if(fields[i] == display) {
          getField(fields[i]).display=display.visible;
        } else {
          getField(fields[i]).display=display.hidden;
        }
    }
}
 
setDisplay("goodsugar")
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за поздния ответ, только на выходных получается проверять код. Первый предоставленный вариант к сожалению не сработает, `countryofgrowth` это вертикальное выпадающее меня в котором пользователь выбирает страну сам. Потому я надеялся эту проблему можно было разрешить похожим способом на `if (countryofgrowth==AcceptableCountries) then setDisplay("goodsugar")`? По поводу сокращения функции установки  полей, она должна сработать, но при проверке у меня почему то постоянно ругается на вот это место `} else {`, я проверю ещё позже может найду в чем дело и отпишу если что. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Проверил еще раз функцию по сокращению устоновки полей, не работает и выдает следующую ошибку 'RangeError: Invalid argument value. Field.display:24:Field code:Calculate'. Спасибо за помощь.